# What does the symbol | mean in Python?

Tags: python, list, set, symbols

Noob question, but I don't know what the symbol | is called or what it means and I can't find anything about it online. Can someone explain it? Why does the following happen? How come the order got switched?

```
>>> L = [ 5 | 3, 4]
>>> set(L)
{4, 7}
>>> L
[7, 4]
```

Comment: As far as the `|` symbol, see answer below.  Ordering is not necessarily preserved with sets.

Comment: It depends upon the type (and for integers it indeed is a [bitwise-or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) operation) - Python is quite flexible and supports `|` via the [`__or__` method/protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types). (A number of other languages also support various operator overloading - so take care to look at the exact types in question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) operator. For your example:

```
   0101 (decimal 5)
OR 0011 (decimal 3)
 = 0111 (decimal 7)
```

(also happens to be the one on Wikipedia)

Notice that for each corresponding pair of bits, if either bit is `1`, then the resulting bit is `1`. If both bits are `0`, then the resulting bit is `0`.

Also note that `|` is not Python-specific, it's pretty universal and exists in most languages.

As for your question about order: [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)s in Python do not preserve order, they are "unordered collections of unique elements" by definition.